# aurora rds grant user with select privileges

Tags: amazon-rds, sql-grant, amazon-aurora

I have recently ported a MySQL database to AWS RDS Aurora.  I cannot seem to do the simple granting privileges tasks on my database.  I can access the clustered MySQL file with the RDS base user.  Once in I execute the following.

```
USE mysql;    
CREATE USER 'myUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';  // This works    
GRANT SELECT ON 'mytable'.* TO 'myUser'@'%';    // Returns 0 rows.
```

I have verified table, etc.

Comment: Operator error :( .  I was using the following query to check for success.: select User, Host, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_priv, Alter_priv, Grant_priv from user order by User;  I should have been using select * from tables_priv;

Answer (score 0):

Your grants look fine (answer mostly going in for posterity's sake).  If you experience a problem like this, the best thing to do is to troubleshoot as follows:

1. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
2. Try with the grantee user, see if the grants in fact are in place
3. If they are, then check your validation logic